# I keep getting an invalid syntax when I try writing my code

Tags: python

I'm new to learning python, and I'm working through a tutorial, and whenever I punch this line in I receive an invalid syntax error.

```
In [4]: mystring = "hello"
In [5]: myfloat = 10.0
In [6]: myint = 20

In [7]: if mystring == "hello":

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if mystring == "hello":
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you copied your code verbatim?

Comment: You probably got a `...` on the next line, and hit <ENTER> again

Comment: Post the code in full

Comment: Please describe your execution environment. What version of Python are you using? How are you invoking it? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: This kind of questions remember me of Nabucodonosor's dream and Daniel...

Comment: Hi! We are trying to figure out your problem but need more details. This looks like an interactive ipython session but the error is "unexpected EOF" and I can't figure out how you can get an EOF on an interactive session. You need at least statement inside the `if`. You would get this EOF error if you tried to run a module with `if mystring == "hello":` as the very last line.